# Reverse words of a sentence in mips

Tags: string, assembly, recursion, mips

You are given a string, like "hello what is your name?"
You have to reverse the words, using a recursive function.
So the result of the example string is "name? your is what hello"
The language is MIPS assembly.

Here is what I have done so far: (The code doesn't end unfortunately :| and I can't find the issue)

```
.macro print_int(%arg)
    li $v0, 1
    add $a0, %arg, $zero
    syscall
.end_macro

.macro print_string(%arg)
    move $t9, $a0
    li $v0, 4
    add $a0, %arg, $zero
    syscall
    move $a0, $t9
.end_macro

.text
    la $s0, string
    li $s1, 32 # space
    la $t8, space

    sub $s0, $s0, 1
    sb $s1, 0($s0)

    # find the length of the string
    move $t0, $s0 # $t0 = i = the iterator
L1:     lb $t1, 0($t0) # $t1 = i'th char of the string  
    beq $t1, 0, Exit # if string[i] == null, Exit
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # i++
    j L1
Exit:
    sub $s3, $t0, $s0 # $s3 is the length of the string
    # Set arguements
    move $a0, $s0
    move $a1, $t0 # endFlag = length of the string


    jal reverse # call the function
    li $v0, 10
    syscall # exit

reverse:
    # save registers
    sub $sp, $sp, 12
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $a1, 8($sp)

    bgt $a1, $s0, L2 # base case
    add $sp, $sp, 12
    jr $ra

    # find a word in the string
L2:
    add $t0, $zero, $a1
    add $t3, $a0, $s3 # address of last character of the string

    Loop:
        lb $t4, 0($t3) # chracter from the string
        seq $v0, $s1, $t4 # if space
        ble $t3, $a0, Exit_Loop # if first of string
        beq $v0, 1, Exit_Loop # if character was space
        sub $t3, $t3, 1
        j Loop
    Exit_Loop:

    sb $zero, 0($t3)
    add $t3, $t3, 1
    print_string($t3)
    print_string($t8)

    #recursive call
    move $a1, $t3
    jal reverse

    # load registers
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    lw $a1, 8($sp)
    add $sp, $sp, 12 # release the stack
    jr $ra

.data
    string: .asciiz "hello what is your name?"
    newline: .asciiz "\n"
    space: .asciiz " "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not stop from entering the function `recursive` even if the string is empty (`$t3 == $a0 + 1`).
Here's a quick fix: replace your code:

```
Exit_Loop:

sb $zero, 0($t3)
add $t3, $t3, 1
print_string($t3)
print_string($t8)

#recursive call
move $a1, $t3
jal reverse
```

with:

```
Exit_Loop:

sb $zero, 0($t3)
add $t4, $t3, 1
print_string($t4)
print_string($t8)

ble $t3, $a0, Exit_Func
#recursive call
move $a1, $t4
jal reverse

Exit_Func:
```

Also, please notice that your macro `print_int` doesn't store/restore the value of `$a0`, also even in `print_string` you store/restore `$a0` using `$t9`, that's still dangerous since according to the `MIPS32 ABI` the values in register `$t[0-9]` are not guaranteed to be reserved during a `syscall` (while in `$s[0-7]` it is guaranteed).

Comment: Thank you. I have got another Q if you don't mind. Now, I want to save that reversed string somewhere in the memory. But I get nowhere. I just know that the lines of code that save each part of the reversed sentence in that place in memory, are located where I have put "print_int(..)"s.

Comment: Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591641/reverse-a-string-and-save-the-reversed-sentence-in-memory

Comment: @user3100883 Sorry for my late response. I was having a crazy and sleepless week to push the progress of my research project and even didn't have time for even some afternoon teas.. I'll have a look at it soon. Sorry again for any inconvenience.